# PowerShell equivalent for Python's requests.post with both data and files

Tags: python, rest, powershell, ckan

I'm trying to make a PowerShell equivalent for this Python code:

```
import requests
requests.post('http://someCKANsite/api/action/resource_create',
              data={"package_id":"my_dataset"},
              headers={"X-CKAN-API-Key": "21a47217-6d7b-49c5-88f9-72ebd5a4d4bb"},
              files=[('upload', file('/path/to/file/to/upload.csv'))])
```

I have tried:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri http://someCKANsite/api/action/resource_create -Headers $headers -InFile $myfile -Body $rcbody -ContentType "multipart/form-data"
```

...with `$headers` containing my `X-CKAN-API-Key` and `$rcbody` containing the `package_id`. But I get the error `Invoke-WebRequest : The cmdlet cannot run because the following conflicting parameters are specified: Body and InFile. Specify either Body or Infile, then retry.`

I've tried putting `?package_id=...` on the end of the Uri, but that doesn't work. I've tried all kinds of combinations in the `Advanced REST client`, but also to no avail. I've also tried `Invoke-RestMethod`, but it has the same hassles.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify both; as the -InFile basically just adds the content of the file as a body (which would conflict) with your existing body.

You can however, construct the body with your file yourself doing something like this (same for invoke-webrequest/or invoke-restmethod):

```
$body = "upload=$(get-content c:\yourfile.csv -Enc Byte -raw)&package_id=my_dataset"
Invoke-RestMethod -Method $method -Headers $headers -Uri ($server+$uri) -body $body
```

Here I just added more parameters in your body by concatting them (&package_id=). You should know how the server processes your parameters.

Are they read from the body (as I'm assuming here) or as a part of the url string? You can easily see how the request is being passed (using e.g. fiddler) when you invoke the python and then adjust the invoke-webrequst/invoke-restmethod thereafter.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble seeing if the file is being uploaded properly. I'm getting a 200 result from the REST Client, but in PowerShell I'm getting a 500 error. And even after the 200 from the REST Client, the file doesn't seem to be uploaded properly. I'm actually using the "resource_update" option now, but even Python is driving me crazy...